# How to import Excel table with double headers into oracle database

Tags: sql, database, excel, oracle

I have this excel table I am trying to transfer over to an oracle database. The thing is that the table has headers that overlap and I'm not sure if there is a way to import this nicely into an Oracle Database.

```
+-----+-----------+-----------+
|     | 2018-01-01| 2018-01-02|
|Item +-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     | RMB | USD | RMB | USD |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

The top headers are just the dates for the month and then their respective data for that date. Is there a way to nicely transfer this to an oracle table?

EDIT: Date field is an actual date such as 02/19/2018.

Comment: I think that you need to transform your excel to  [item,date, rmb, usd ] columns  and then load it to the corresponding table.

Answer (score 0):

If you pre-create a table (as I do), then you can start loading from the 3rd line (i.e. skip the first two), putting every Excel column into the appropriate Oracle table column.

Alternatively (& obviously), rename column headers so that file wouldn't have two header levels).

Comment: Thank you, but how would I be able to distinguish a value from one date vs from another date when I try to query them?

Comment: Aha! "Date", as a header, is a real date (such as 19.02.2018). I thought that it is a string, literally "Date". So, this is actually a "matrix" type of a file. I'm not sure (read: I don't know how) that there is a simple way to do it.

Comment: Ah yes, its an actually date, sorry if I didn't specify enough. Would I have to restructure the whole table then?

Comment: What does the Oracle table actually look like?

Comment: I am trying to create a new table, it currently doesn't look like anything

Comment: figure out your data model, then the answer will be simple :)